# Vegetarian diet for a combat sport athlete?

Tags: boxing

I'd like to save some money by removing meat and dairy from my diet.

I am planning to give a go a diet where I am consuming mostly fruits and beans.

My only concern is how it will impact my energy levels and overall health as a boxer.

Is this type of diet ok for an athlete who is in a combat sport?

Comment: What evidence shows that removing meat and dairy from you diet will save you money? What research/reading have you already done on vegetarian diets for boxers?

Comment: It's almost always cheaper to live on a purely vegetarian diet in most locations. The only caveat is that you must prepare your own food, rather than buying prepackaged convenience foods. And you should prefer frozen and dried bulk foods to fresh. Fruits would be the most expensive thing in this diet, since fruit has to be fresh, so those you buy in-season and on sale only. Meat is generally going to come out to be a lot more expensive for the amount of calories and protein it provides than vegetarian bulk foods. And studies show fast food is actually more expensive than making your own.

Answer (score 7):

Carefully planned vegetarian and vegan diets do provide adequate nutrition for athletes. The active phrase being, "carefully planned".

Martial artists don't have any special nutritional requirements compared with people who do other activities.

As for energy levels, this depends on what kind of fuel you're putting in you. When you eat simple carbohydrates, you're going to get a spike in your energy levels and a temporary boost, but it won't last. That's why you want to fill your diet with complex carbohydrates and protein instead. Fruit is fine, also, because it comes with the fiber that slows down digestion. Fruit juice may not be a good idea, since it lacks the fiber and digests quickly.

Most athletes who have gone vegan tend to say that they went vegan because they found that it raised their energy levels and endurance. They also say it improved their recovery times. You can find even some vegans, or people who go vegan while training for a fight, who were in the UFC. There are vegan iron man triathletes. There are vegan boxers. There are vegan tennis players and runners. There are vegan major league baseball players. Etc.

Vegan and vegetarian diets don't seem to slow people down.

The protein requirements of a vegan athlete aren't much higher than the average couch potato, either. You can definitely find vegan protein sources that will give you more than enough protein. The beans you mentioned are a perfect example.

Incidentally, here is a great article that discusses protein requirements of athletes and weightlifters in particular. The best available science says that people don't need the huge amounts of protein that most athletes and weightlifters say we need:

http://bayesianbodybuilding.com/the-myth-of-1glb-optimal-protein-intake-for-bodybuilders/

For health in general, vegan and vegetarian diets have many health advantages and some disadvantages. The disadvantages don't generally cause people to give up the diet. You definitely want to get a vitamin B12 supplement and take it daily. Some vegetarians may also bruise more easily, but there are diet choices that can make that better if it does seem to be happening to you.

You should take a look at the American Dietetic Association's "Official Position" paper on vegetarian and vegan diets. They specifically talk about athletes. And they make it clear that even a strict vegan diet is fine for all stages of life and for athletes:

http://www.vrg.org/nutrition/2009_ADA_position_paper.pdf

Also, many have questioned whether soy protein in particular and many other plant-based proteins have an estrogen-like compound in them which might cause men to lose testosterone. First, it's important to realize that vegans and vegetarians don't require soy protein at all. There are plenty of alternatives to soy. Second, the answer is emphatically: No! This has been sufficiently disproved.

Here are some articles I gathered that discuss this:

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20378106
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19524224
http://www.foodnavigator.com/Science/Review-finds-no-effect-of-soy-on-testosterone
http://www.foodproductiondaily.com/Safety-Regulation/Review-finds-no-effect-of-soy-on-testosterone
http://www.foodconsumer.org/newsite/Nutrition/Food/180820091053_nutrition_notes_men_don_t_need_to_fear_soy_foods.html
http://www.ironmanmagazine.com/soy-and-your-testosterone/
http://jacknorrisrd.com/soy-protein-weightlifting-and-testosterone/
http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/drobson71.htm

Now, getting back to your particular diet idea, which is to consume only fruits and beans. That is a very different diet than a typical vegan diet. I think you would be well advised to talk with a nutritionist before making such an extreme diet change. At the very least, make sure your new diet has enough calories to support your weight and activity level and satisfies all the recommended dietary allowances (RDA) of vitamins, minerals, protein, carbohydrate, fat, sodium, and so on. And definitely take a vitamin B12 supplement.

Lastly, there is a ton of misinformation on the web about vegan and vegetarian diets. If you listen to them, no vegetarian should even be alive, let alone living to old age.

By the way, the lifespan of vegans is no different than the general population in the U.S. So we at least know it's not going to cause you to have an early death. Even more positively, it has been observed that populations in various parts of the world that produce the most numbers of people that live past age 100 tend to eat very little meat and plenty of plant-based products. Not generally "no" meat, mind you. Just very little of it.

The bottom line is: Don't take anything you read on the web as truth until you've had a chance to verify it. The best way to do that is to find any peer-reviewed, scientific papers which support the claims. That usually isn't good enough, however, because you might not be able to interpret the results properly. So if you can, ask some non-biased experts on nutrition for their thoughts on it if it's not immediately obvious what the paper is saying.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

"fruit and beans" will not provide a sufficiently balanced long term diet, especially when the requirements of being a moderate to high level athlete.

And yes, some population groups in history had similar diets. They also where several inches shorter, and unless you're a descendant of those groups, they may very well have had genetic and gut microbiome adaptions to that diet.

Tread carefully, it's your health, right?

While I would never suggest someone cut out meat or dairy (absent specific conditions for dairy), if you're going to do it use something like nutritiondata.self.com and do other *real* medical/scientific research (not just asking on vegan/vegetarian boards) and make sure you're getting the nutrition you need. Nutritiondata.self.com is kind of neat because it will give you a solid nutrition profile of the food, and in some cases recommend a complementary food to balance it out (mostly with the Amino Acid completeness).

See here: http://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/fruits-and-fruit-juices/1927/2 in the "Protein Quality" box at the bottom of the box there is a "Find foods with complementary profile" box that brings up a list including brazil nuts and other kinds of seeds.

It is possible to be vegan and have a healthy diet, but it takes a lot of work and at least for the first year or two you should consider having blood work done every 3 or 4 months to make sure you're not getting low on anything.

Vegetarian is easier because of cheese and eggs.

If you've got moral or religious reasons to drop meat, well, that's your thing and I wish you the best. If it's just economics I don't think you'll save a lot of money. In the US (your profiles says you're in Brooklyn) there's lots of inexpensive meats available, and often times getting quality vegetables and fruits is expensive.

Either way, if you approach it carefully it should not impact your martial arts.

Editing to add, because I can't comment:

The 1g of protein per pound of body weight link mentioned in the other response is a rule of thumb. Body builders and weight lifters like their rules of thumb and they like them simple.

In their world a little too much protein is better than not quite enough protein, and if you're doing things to artificially increase your T levels, or doing other "non-natural" things to shorten recovery times and increase protein synthesis then you might be out where a study doesn't look.

Also we (humans) like round numbers and simple math. We don't spar in 2 minute 48.7 second rounds, we don't run "four and a 3/8" miles, and we don't eat ".73 grams of protein per pound of lean body weight".

1 gram per pound is easy to calculate.

And yes, if you're not lifting 2x a week for size/weight, then having *lots* of protein isn't useful. Having enough is important.

Also (with soy) keep in mind that many populations that eat lots of it tend to eat a fermented soy product (miso, natto) and less of the unfermented stuff (tofu). Fermenting tends to get rid of the phytic acid and break down the phyto-estrogen.

Remember that any culture with 30 (or more) generations of a similar diet might have genetic adaptions. Inuit in Greenland have a high fat diet. They also have genetic divergence that seems to reduce their own bodies production of omega-3 and 6. Choosing to consume omega-3 supplements based on studies of Inuit might be counter productive unless your grandparents lived on ice floes. Or maybe not.

Answer (score 0):

The effectiveness of a vegetarian diet, like any other, is dependent on the types and amounts of foods you eat.  Do some research. Make sure that the food choices you make are diverse enough to cover all of you dietary needs. Despite what the multi-billion dollar supplement industry would have you believe, it is always best to get your requisite vitamins, minerals, and other trace elements directly from the foods you consume. As you adjust to training as a vegetarian, pay close attention to what your body is telling you, and make any necessary alterations to your protein and carbohydrate intake to optimize your energy level. A lot of people who switch from an omnivorous diet to a vegetarian one encounter periods where their energy levels drastically drop, and this can be fixed through minor adjustments of meal composition, size, and frequency.

It's worth noting that, historically, many Roman gladiators maintained an almost totally vegetarian diet.

Comment: Roman gladiators' diet was meant to make them fat [source](http://archive.archaeology.org/0811/abstracts/gladiator.html), or rather to gain a thick layer of fat over their athletic bodies. It would protect their muscles and joints from wounds: a cut or stab first needed to puncture said thick layer of fat before doing serious damage. This is why gladiators are always depicted as [massive](http://madamepickwickartblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/gladiator1.jpg). *I would not recommend this diet to anyone.*

Comment: The conclusions of the article you linked seem spurious. The dietary conclusions are based on the chemical composition of gladiator bones. There is no evidence that supports that gladiators were fat, and plenty of evidence that they were not. A thick layer of fat would be of negligible benefit in combat, and it would certainly have detrimental factors.  Surviving art almost always depicts gladiators as muscular exemplars of physical prowess (as seen in surviving paintings, prose, and poetry on the subject). Modern vegetarians are no more prone to carrying excess fat than people who eat meat.